# Concatenating string with exception message

Tags: c#, string, exception, concatenation, xsd-validation

I am trying to catch an exception when my XSD is invalid and just display a message on the console detailing to the user what went wrong. However the message that is displayed on the console is not as I expected.

```
try
{
    // doing stuff here
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Schema " + e.Message);
    return false;
}
```

I expected the output to be something like:

```
"ERROR: Schema ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '>'. Line 15, position 38."
```

However the output that I get is:

```
"' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '>'. Line 15, position 38."
```

My string at the beginning is not displayed before the message.

I have tried storing the values in two strings and tried concatenating those 2 string with no success. Ideally I would like one string that contains the concatenation of both the 'ERROR' part and the message produced by the exception.

Comment: If you debug, does it hit that breakpoint? It could be possible that you're catching the wrong exception

Comment: Why is there only one single quote at the start of the message? I think that's a big clue. I would expect single quotes around the unexpected token.

Comment: I have changed it to Catch(Exception e) and the same behavior results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your schema contains a newline. The text `ERROR: Schema '` must be somewhere higher in the output window.

You can check this using:

```
catch (XmlException e)
{
    string message = "ERROR: Schema " + e.Message;
    message = message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
    message = message.Replace("\n", "");
    message = message.Replace("\r", "");

    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This produces the same result: ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '>'. Line 15, position 38.

Comment: That did the trick! So I guess there was some whitespace character? I don't understand why I didn't see both parts of the output anywhere on the console though?

Comment: If you can't see `ERROR: Schema '` higher up somewhere, that means your schema contained a carriage return (`\r`).

Comment: Good thinking Yogesh, without the actual console output at hand. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
try
{
    // doing stuff here
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    errorMessage = "ERROR: Schema " + e.Message.toString();

    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage );
    return false;
}
```